# How and where to find out details on which directories and files a package effects?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, repository, documentation

In the context of adding [capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64011435/4531180) to `BaseX`,I can see some information about a package:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ apt show basex
Package: basex
Version: 9.0.1+ds-1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/database
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Alexander Holupirek <alex@holupirek.de>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 4,059 kB
Depends: java-wrappers, default-jre | java8-runtime
Recommends: libjline2-java
Suggests: libtagsoup-java, libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java, libjing-java
Homepage: http://basex.org
Download-Size: 3,611 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
Description: XML database and XPath/XQuery processor
 BaseX is a very fast and light-weight, yet powerful XML database and
 XPath/XQuery processor, including support for the latest W3C Full Text and
 Update Recommendations. It supports large XML instances and offers a highly
 interactive front-end (basexgui). Apart from two local standalone modes, BaseX
 offers a client/server architecture.
 .
 The package provides following commands:
  * basex  ..........  Standalone local XML database. Command line interface.
  * basexgui  .......  Standalone local XML database. Graphical user interface.
  * basexserver  ....  BaseX XML Database Server.
  * basexclient  ....  BaseX XML Database Client.
 BaseX XML database and XPath/XQuery processor

nicholas@mordor:~$
```

but how do I find out more, such as [where](https://superuser.com/q/1604263/977796) the `lib` directory is for `BaseX`?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ dpkg -L basex
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/basex
/usr/bin/basexclient
/usr/bin/basexgui
/usr/bin/basexserver
/usr/share
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/basexgui.desktop
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/basex
/usr/share/doc/basex/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/basex/copyright
/usr/share/doc/basex/examples
/usr/share/doc/basex/examples/input.xml
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/icons/hicolor
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/192x192
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/36x36
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/36x36/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/72x72
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/72x72/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/96x96
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/apps/basex.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/basex.svg
/usr/share/java
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/basex.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/basexclient.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/basexgui.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/basexserver.1.gz
/usr/share/maven-repo
/usr/share/maven-repo/org
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex/9.0.1
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex/9.0.1/basex-9.0.1.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex/9.0.1/basex-9.0.1.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex/debian
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex/debian/basex-debian.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex-parent
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex-parent/9.0.1
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex-parent/9.0.1/basex-parent-9.0.1.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex-parent/debian
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex-parent/debian/basex-parent-debian.pom
/usr/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/pixmaps/basex_16x16.xpm
/usr/share/pixmaps/basex_32x32.xpm
/usr/share/java/basex.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex/debian/basex-debian.jar
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Yet, I'm looking the `lib` directory to `BaseX` itself.

Comment: Please [don’t cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/285232).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lib` directory can be found in the full distributions of BaseX, which can be downloaded from the official homepage. See [Startup: Full Distributions](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Startup#Full_Distributions) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `basex` has any `lib` content, just the `bin`.

`dpkg -L basex` does not return anything in the lib directory, so it's certainly not in the `basex` package.  It could be in `basex-dev` or something similar, but when I look for that I find:

```
$ apt search basex
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
basex/testing,testing 9.0.1+ds-1 all
  XML database and XPath/XQuery processor

lua-basexx/testing,testing 0.3-2 all
  baseXX encoding/decoding library for Lua
```

If I look at the contents of `lua-basexx`, I also see nothing in `lib`:

```
$ apt-file list lua-basexx
lua-basexx: /usr/share/doc/lua-basexx/changelog.Debian.gz
lua-basexx: /usr/share/doc/lua-basexx/copyright
lua-basexx: /usr/share/lua/5.1/basexx.lua
lua-basexx: /usr/share/lua/5.2/basexx.lua
```

Our last option is to search for `libbasex.so`:

```
$ apt-file search libbasex
$
```

This returns nothing, so there is no file starting with `libbasex` in the debian archive.

Comment: BaseX is a Java program, so it typically wouldn’t use a `libbasex.so` library. `apt-file search` matches anywhere in a file’s path, not just at the start — see `apt-file search man5/s` for example.

Comment: I'm confused, because I'm trying to find "where" to add `JAR` files for `BaseX` to pickup.  Apparently, that's the "lib" folder for the db itself.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -L` lists all the files shipped in a given package; to get a full picture of the changes made to the system, you’d also have to look at the package’s maintainer scripts, but `basex` doesn’t have any.

BaseX is a Java program, so its libraries aren’t in `lib...` files; they are provided as JARs, shipped in `/usr/share/maven-repo` (which is structured as a Maven repository), and linked in `/usr/share/java`. The BaseX “library” (which also contains all the BaseX applications) is `/usr/share/maven-repo/org/basex/basex/9.0.1/basex-9.0.1.jar`.

I’m not sure the packaged version of BaseX will load JARs automatically from any given directory, but you can always add JARs to the classpath; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64965956/4500798) for details.

Comment: Right, but, to add `JAR` files for the db to pick-up, there's "a" lib directory.  Or so is my understanding.

Comment: Are you referring to [this feature](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Repository)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64011435/4531180  so possibly that feature.  The `JAR` for `JDBC` would have to go somewhere.  I was expecting a "lib" folder.  I added the above link to the question for context.

Comment: OK, I’ve answered that part of your question there.